# How to replace every second element?

Tags: d

I have string `cccccc` (6 `c`). I need to replace every first `c` to `a` and every second to `b` to get: `ababab`. Is it's possible to do with `map`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add indices to a range using [enumerate](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#.enumerate):

```
import std.algorithm, std.stdio, std.range;

void main(){
        "cccccc"
                .enumerate
                .map!(a => a[0] % 2 ? 'b' : 'a')
                .writeln;
}
```

`a[0]` is the index, `a[1]` the value.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about enumerate. Thanks!

Comment: @weltensturm, how to fix code, if, foe example I need replace symbol not with single letter, but with `'bb'` and `'aa'` ?

Comment: `"bb"` and `"aa"` (double quotes), and then `.join` the map result

Comment: @weltensturm thanks! And what if in `ccccc` string there is another symbols like: `cscsgacgcec` and I want to do same, but skip non `c` symbols?